# Plot a variogram with angle and lag

Tags: r, graphics

I have a output of variogram command :

```
my.var=variogram(z~1, data=data,alpha=a=seq.int(0,180,1))
head(my.var)


  np dist gamma dir.hor dir.ver id
1 120 0.04081633 0.0001896105 0 0 var1
2 101 0.08163265 0.0006882740 0 0 var1
3  82 0.12244898 0.0013919039 0 0 var1
4  64 0.16326531 0.0021475156 0 0 var1
5  48 0.20408163 0.0027826922 0 0 var1
6  36 0.24489796 0.0031126833 0 0 var1
```

I am able to create a cloud of points with :

```
plot3d(my.var$dir.hor,my.var$dist,my.var$gamma)
```

but if i want create something like this : [variogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx6gM.png) what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

I had something very similar for my dissertation, I found this document helped a lot in creating 3D wireframe plots:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/vignettes/st.pdf

It is written by the guys who wrote the `gstat` packages for R. It's a little difficult to work out but gives a pretty good 3d plot surface.